# How can I detect programmatically if two threads/processes are pinned to the same core

Tags: c++, linux

I am developing a multithreaded program where each important thread is pinned to its own core. It is easy to keep track of used cores within the program and prevent two threads from being pinned to the same core (due to erroneous config).

There is now an another process in the same machine which also pins to a core. I would like to prevent these processes from being pinned to the same core by accident.

I can detect this situation from command line but I would like to do this from within the program and prevent the second one from starting.

Is there a way to do this? Environment is Ubuntu and C++

I can introduce delay to the second process to go around any race conditions that might be there due to two processes starting at the same time

Comment: Have you actually measured that this will lead to a performance increase? In my experience fiddling with thread priorities/affinities isn't always beneficial and just adds complexity of its own. And yes there are cases too where thread affinity is beneficial, but from my (windows) experience that is a property you set on a thread not a property you get assigned (or you set process affinities as a whole)

Comment: Can you set the other process to always pin to a particular well-known core, and then just avoid pinning to that core yourself?

Comment: You could find the other process and compare allowed cpus in `/proc/XX/status`. Or [list all processes from a core](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349908/how-to-get-all-processes-running-on-each-cpu-core-in-ubuntu) and look for the other process.

Comment: Your options are to ask the OS (ie, by reading `/proc`) or to write some external process to track & broker CPU assignments. The first works for all processes in principle, but only ones running as your user

Comment: The second can work across users but only with processes you deliberately integrate with this broker

Comment: If this is a more general "is there any process with a non-trivial pin that uses this core?", then that would be some traversal of `/proc/$PID/status` again.

Comment: This is classic example of question with [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Do you needs some kind of Real-time computing? Why you think you have to know threads are on same CPU core?

Comment: Had one job where it turned out the most efficient way to run the program was to bind all but one of the threads to the same core. Sat down a few years later after I had some street cred at the company and rewrote the program without threads. Wasn't any faster, but it was a whole lot simpler.